# Tile-Base Movement

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I tried to make a Tile-Base Movement in XNA but I don't know how.  My tiles are 32x32, and sprite is the same size.

This is the code I use to move sprite:

```
    if ( Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        Position.Y -= Speed.Y;
    }
    if ( Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        Position.Y += Speed.Y;
    }
```

... and the same with the other 2 keys.

I want my sprite moves smooth, one exact tile at the time, but not "jump" to the tile.
Sorry for my bad English, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position of your sprite based on the amount of time that has elapsed.

So if your speed is 32px per second, and the elapsed time is 60th second (60fps), then you need to only move the sprite `32 * (1/60)` pixels per update.

Use the `Update(GameTime gameTime)` parameter to get how much time has elapsed since the last update.

Comment: Ok but the sprite stops moving when I stop pressing the key, and don't   reach the other tile. Speed is: 32 * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

Comment: you need to set a target position, rather than just when the key is pressed. So set a field that denotes the target position and continue moving until that value is reached.